# Yii command not work

Tags: php, yii

My table rows is data(date time), name(var char), address(var char)

```
$command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$command->from('news_hamkar');
$command->where(date('Y-m-d').'  < DATE_ADD(data, INTERVAL -2 DAY)');        
$command->order('news_hamkar.data desc');
$command->queryAll();
```

Why doesn't the Yii command work correctly?

Comment: not working? its a broad term. post the unexpected results.

Comment: Reworded for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date isn't quoted, resulting in your where condition being incorrect. If run today, the date would be 2015-03-07. However, MySQL will interpret that as arithmetic and end up with the following where condition:

```
2005 < DATE_ADD(data, INTERVAL -2 DAY)
```

To avoid that, pass the date as a parameter:

```
$command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$command->from('news_hamkar');
$command->where(':date < DATE_ADD(data, INTERVAL -2 DAY)');        
$command->order('news_hamkar.data desc');
$command->queryAll(true,array('date'=>date('Y-m-d'));
```

Comment: Glad to help. I've made this error myself a few times, so I've become a bit more perceptive in spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems with the code posted in question. I assume you are trying same code in your application.
1. you are missing `select` statement.
2. where are you storing the results returned by `queryAll()`?
try this

```
$command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$command->select('*');//added select statement
$command->from('news_hamkar');
$command->where(date('Y-m-d').'  < DATE_ADD(data, INTERVAL -2 DAY)');        
$command->order('news_hamkar.data desc');//save results to $results
$results=$command->queryAll();
```